# what happened to this graph with scale when using Show to LogPlot?

Tags: graphics, logarithmic-scale

```
p1 = Plot[8 x^3, {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True]
p2 = LogLogPlot[8 x^3, {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True]
```

Both graph look fine.
However, when trying to put them together for demonstration of transforming to linear relationship when taking logs, the graph does not seem to have the proper scale any more?

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: the begin and the end points of the shorter curve are `Point[Log/@{{.5,8*.5^3},{3.5,8*3.5^3}}`, for which it just uses the **logged ticks of `p2`**, not the initial one(shown in front of us), when `Show` combines them. the conjecture above can be repeated once one uses `LogPlot` for `p3`, and gets the curve in which x ranges from .5 to 3.5, and y ranges from `Log[8*.5^3]` to `Log[8*3.5^3]` at the `Show` ticks.

Comment: @SHBooKP I might have guessed it. Is there a better way to put them together then? for demonstration purpose?

Comment: In principle, in `Show[p1,p2,p3,...]` the whole image inherits the properties of the first object, that is, of `p1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you would like to combine two plots with different scaling of one or two axes, better use `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`  as follows

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][p1, p2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoXY"]
```

[image]

this is only for a better presentation

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 Plot[8 x^3, {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Linear", "Linear", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}], 
    Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}]}], 
 LogLogPlot[8 x^3, {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Log", "Log", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[{Red, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}]], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoXY"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason I guessed is above in my comment, and plus @Alexei added, which implies that mma takes the scales and axis, etc as the first argument in function `Show`.

If you only want to put them together for demonstration purpose, maybe you can use `Overlay` function shown below:

```
f[x_] := 8 x^3; p1 = 
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0.5, 3.5}, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, f[.5]}, Frame -> None, 
  AxesStyle -> Green];
p2 = LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 0.5, 3.5}, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, f[.5]}, 
   Frame -> None];
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

the overlay is:

[image: overlay]

What's more, you can set the axes, ticks, color and so on to demonstrate it more vividly.

(But whatever, I think put two plots with different scaling function together is a little 无理取闹的(I don't know how to express the word in English...))